# How can I fix my neighbor counting for my maze generation?

Tags: python, debugging, multidimensional-array, pygame, maze

My issue is with my `def countNeighbours(self, grid)` function. In the grid, every cell is surround by four walls making each of them rectangles. I decided to use the wrap around method where the an edge cell'
s neighbor is on the other side. This way none of the indices will be out of bounds. However now I've run into the problem where the maze pathing goes straight down and breaks. I can't comprehend why exactly.
[Screenshot of the bug](https://i.gyazo.com/c286e6efbfa12851caf30d808f5cae64.png).

The goal was for the maze pathing to randomly visited a couple cells and destroy the walls before stopping. Then I'd move on the the backtracking step.

Here is the entire code:

```py
import pygame
import random
pygame.init()
screenWidth = 604
screenHeight = 604
FPS = 60

# Colors
Red = (255, 0, 0)
Blue = (0, 100, 200, 50)
Green = (0, 200, 100, 50)
White = (255, 255, 255)
Black = (0, 0, 0)

# TODO: FIX THE COUNTING FUNCTION- MESSES UP THE PATHING


class Cell:
    def __init__(self, i, j):
        self.i = i  # Row
        self.j = j  # Column
        self.visited = False
        # Checks to see if wall(s) of the cell exists
        # Order:   Top,  Right, Bottom, Left
        self.wall = [True, True, True, True]

    def draw(self, surface):
        x = self.i * length
        y = self.j * length
        # Our Path in Green
        if self.visited:
            pygame.draw.rect(displayWindow, Green, (x, y, length, length))
        # Top Line                             Start Pos,  End Pos
        if self.wall[0]:
            pygame.draw.line(displayWindow, White, (x, y), (x + length, y), 1)
        # Right Line
        if self.wall[1]:
            pygame.draw.line(displayWindow, White, (x + length, y), (x + length, y + length), 1)
        # Bottom
        if self.wall[2]:
            pygame.draw.line(displayWindow, White, (x + length, y + length), (x, y + length), 1)
        # Left
        if self.wall[3]:
            pygame.draw.line(displayWindow, White, (x, y + length), (x, y), 1)
        self.changed = False

    # Function adds the unvisited to the cell's neighbor array and returns the next cell
    def countNeighbors(self, grid):
        global x, y
        self.neighbors = []
        top = grid[(((self.i + 1) + x) % x)][self.j]
        right = grid[self.i][(((self.j + 1) + y) % y)]
        bottom = grid[(((self.i - 1) + x) % x)][self.j]
        left = grid[self.i][(((self.j - 1) + y) % y)]

        # If the neighbor cell is unvisited add to array
        if not top.visited:
            self.neighbors.append(top)
        if not right.visited:
            self.neighbors.append(right)
        if not bottom.visited:
            self.neighbors.append(bottom)
        if not left.visited:
            self.neighbors.append(left)
        # pick random unvisted cell as our next
        if len(self.neighbors) > 0:
            p = random.randrange(0, len(self.neighbors))
            return self.neighbors[p]

    # Highlights the current cell
    def marker(self):
        x = self.i * length
        y = self.j * length
        pygame.draw.rect(displayWindow, Blue, (x, y, length, length))


# Rows and Columns, length will be our width of each cell
length = 40
rows = screenWidth // length
cols = screenHeight // length
print(rows, cols)

# store cells
grid = [[]*cols]*rows
for i in range(rows):
    for j in range(cols):
        cell = Cell(i, j)
        grid[i].append(cell)
current = grid[0][0]
x = len(grid)
y = len(grid[i])


def display(surface):
    global current
    for i in range(len(grid)):
        for j in range(len(grid[i])):
            grid[i][j].draw(surface)
    # Mark first cell as visited
    current.visited = True
    current.marker()
    # Check neighbors of current cell
    nextCell = current.countNeighbors(grid)
    if nextCell:
        nextCell.visited = True
        deleteWall(current, nextCell)
        current = nextCell


def deleteWall(a, b):
    # Right and Left Walls
    p = a.i - b.i
    if p == 1:      # neighbor to the left
        a.wall[3] = False
        b.wall[1] = False
    elif p == -1:  # neighbor to the right
        a.wall[1] = False
        b.wall[3] = False
    # Top and Bottom Walls
    q = a.j - b.j
    if q == 1:     # neighbor above
        a.wall[0] = False
        b.wall[2] = False
    elif q == -1:  # neighbor below
        a.wall[2] = False
        b.wall[0] = False


displayWindow = pygame.display.set_mode((screenWidth, screenHeight))
pygame.display.set_caption("Maze Generator")


def main():
    global FPS
    FPSclock = pygame.time.Clock()
    running = True
    while running:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                running = False

        FPSclock.tick(FPS)
        display(displayWindow)
        pygame.display.update()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the bug:

```
grid = [[]*cols]*rows
```

And the correct functions were:

```py
    def countNeighbors(self, grid):
        global x, y
        self.neighbors = []
        # Edge Cases
        # Top Cell
        if self.j == 0:
            self.neighbors.append(None)
        else:
            self.neighbors.append(grid[self.i][self.j - 1])
        # Right
        if self.i == x - 1:
            self.neighbors.append(None)
        else:
            self.neighbors.append(grid[self.i + 1][self.j])
        # Bottom
        if self.j == y - 1:
            self.neighbors.append(None)
        else:
            self.neighbors.append(grid[self.i][self.j + 1])
        # Left
        if self.i == 0:
            self.neighbors.append(None)
        else:
            self.neighbors.append(grid[self.i - 1][self.j])


grid = []
for i in range(rows):
    column = []
    for j in range(cols):
        cell = Cell(i, j)
        column.append(cell)
    grid.append(column)


def display(surface):
    global current
    for i in range(len(grid)):
        for j in range(len(grid[i])):
            grid[i][j].draw(surface)
            grid[i][j].countNeighbors(grid)

    current.visited = True
    current.marker()
    next = random.choice(current.neighbors)
    if next and not next.visited:
        next.visited = True
        deleteWall(current, next)
        current = next
```